# How to check in a file after edits/tags are entered in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp, check-in

I have a power app that allows users to upload, edit, and tag their files onto SharePoint. My app uses a flow that works for adding the files, edits, and tags but I need it to check in the file once all of this is complete. I have tried adding the Check In option to my flow at the end but it overrides all the edits/tags that were entered and will check in the file without the required tags. How can I add the check in feature to my flow that will check in the file after the edits/tags are added and not before?